# Getting segmentation fault after while loop

Tags: c

Hi i have a project for tommorrow which i want to finish but im stuck. Im pretty new at this so don't be harsh.Basicly i want my program to ask how many numbers did the user play. How much money, after it asks for the lottery numbers and puts then in a border,then it asks for the users numbers,puts in on a second border and then i want to compare the 2 of them and if they have a same number it will add to 'sum'.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
  int main()
{
int k[20],i;
int k2[12],f;
int numbers,sum,n,l,num;
float money,winnings;
l=0;
sum=0;
printf("How many numbers from 1 to 12?\n");
scanf("%d",&num);
  printf("How much money?\n");
  scanf("%f",&money);
    for (i=0;i<19;i++)
     {printf("Give lottery numbers\n");
        scanf("%d",&k[i]);}
while (l<num){
     printf("Give your numbers\n"); 
     scanf("%d", k2 + f); !!fixed!!
       l++;}
for (f=0;f<num;f++){
  for (i=0;i>19;i++){   !!fixed!!
    if ((k[i])==(k2[f])) !!! and here i think its a mistake. 
{
sum=sum+1;
     }
   }  
 }
printf("You got %d numbers out of %d",sum,num);
   if ((sum=1) && (num=1));
     {winnings=(money*2,5);
        printf("Won %f",winnings);}
   if ((sum=1) && (num=2));
     {winnings=(money*1);
        printf("won %f",winnings);}
   if ((sum=2) && (num=2));
     {winnings=(money*5);
        printf("Won %f",winnings);}
system("pause");}
```

Comment: First format this mess properly. As-is it is unreadable. Then: what is the question? See [ask].

Comment: Well im not quite sure what you mean format but i think i made it.

Comment: This is better, but it still looks horrible. For some inexplicable reason, in several places the code loses its indentation, and starts again from the left margin. Most editors have an automatic indentation feature. Learn how to use it.

Comment: You almost certainly don't want the `;`s after those `if`s

Comment: if i place the ; it makes the loop go just once and then stop?

Comment: `for (i=0;i>19;i++){   !!fix!!` I think you mean `for (i=0;i<19;i++){`

Comment: yeah i changed that too. at the end. where there is    printf("You got %d numbers out of %d",sum,num);  i always get  'you got 0 out of 4' even if i get all 4 of them.

Comment: `if` is not a loop. `;` ends a statement. `if` proceeds to the next instruction if the condition is met. Placing the `;` ends the `if`, separating it from the next instruction. End result whatever happens in the `if`, the code that follows always runs.

Comment: man damn its hard to understand it. anyway 1 last fix i think. when i run it everything is fine but last 3 if they all are true but how can that be? what do i need to change

Comment: Rolled the question back to before you changed the code and invalidated all of the answers. This undid my code formatting, but such is life. Now at least the answers answers make sense. @ΝίκοςΣωτηρίου once you start getting answers it's in very poor taste to move the goalposts by changing the question. You can add, you can clarify, but don't screw with people's answers. If you've changed a lot and are still having problems, ask a new question.

Comment: @user4581301 so i shouldnt change the edit? i don't do it to get people's nerves out, im just trying to find answers is that really bad? i made this post and i ask the questions i have here why would i make a whole new thread? Anyway if you could help me with my question it would be really nice.

Comment: Best not to change the question in a way that makes the answers irrelevant. If you have gotten past this problem and now have another, ask a new question. Sprawling questions do little to help those who follow.

Comment: @user4581301 as i think you know about it too, you can ask 1 question every 3 days, and i have to end this today so im kinda short on time. im trying to do this for 6 hours and i don't know much. Im sorry if i offended somebody but im trying to get this to work

Comment: @ΝίκοςΣωτηρίου: This is no tutorial site, nor a live-debugging forum. Please follow the link I provided. Also read the [C info-page](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/c/info) before posting a question. That will save your and our time!

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't appear that `f` has ever been initialized to anything. Therefore,

```
scanf("%d",k2[f]);
```

Will result in undefined behavior, and is the likely cause of the crash.

Additionally, you need to fix your indentation. Furthermore, your loop is off by one. You initialize `l` to 1, then execute the following loop, whose apparent purpose is reading `num` numbers:

```
while (l<num){
```

So, if, for example, "1" was entered, in order to read only one number, the body of the loop will never execute, since the comparison "1<1" will be false.

It's likely there are other problems with this code, hard to analyze it due to bad indentation.

Comment: 'l' is =0; from the begining. and i didn't quite understand what you said about the scanf("%d",k2[f]);

Comment: No, 'l' is not 0. This code clearly says "l=1;" at the start. Did you actually write this code yourself, or copied it from someone else?

Comment: Oh well.. im doing the code in tutorialspoint online compiler and i had l=0; there. i wrote it myself

Comment: I need some more help.. when  i run it at the end all if are true and it shows all winnings there is. what's wrong? *EDIT* also i always get that the user got 1 out of 'num' even if he gets like 4-4 3-4

Answer (score 1):

This loop

```
     for (i=0;i=19;i++){
```

will never end since i=19 will evaluate to always true.

I think that the intention was:

```
    for (i=0;i<19;i++){
```

Comment: This is true, but this was not the reason for the crash.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik True! But he is not talking about crash but generic problems in his program.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of l, what you probably intended, you are using f, which, as Sam Varshavchik spotted already, is not initialized.

Additionally, you are not passing a pointer to scanf: `scanf("%d", k2[f]);`. You need `scanf("%d", k2 + l);` instead, or `scanf("%d", &k2[l])`, if you prefer.